# Rails4 : live or faye or polling - Reload page when background job is finished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, live, long-polling, sidekiq

I have a background job (Sidekiq) that generate a pdf and save it on S3 with paperclip.
During the process, I present a "waiting page" to the user.

I'm wondering how to auto-reload the waiting page with the pdf once the background job is completed.
I know how to present the pdf inline when it exists (when background job is finished).
I know how to check if it exist on page load, but I need the auto check its presence till success.

I did my homework and checked what are the possible solutions :

- **Polling** - seems to be an outdated solution, not the most efficient one
- **ActiveRecord::Live::SSE** - Seems to be interesting but complex to my new knowledge on "livestreaming". And not compatible with IE (even it's not a blocker, It is still a con)
- **Faye and websocket** - Still, I have difficulties to understand how to implement it regarding my need.

Could you please help me on what is the best technique, and the proper way to implement it? (mostly the timeout part on poll, and the reload part for live::sse and faye). Most examples show chat apps, which make me wonder if I'm on the right track.